# Sample function with probabilities dependent on another column

Tags: r, probability, sample

I am using R and would like to randomly assign a status to rows, with a probability that depends on a particular column value.

My table (called df) looks like this:

```
Year    Level  Country    
2018    1      Eng
2018    2      Wal
2018    1      Eng
2019    3      Sco
```

etc...  There are three possible levels (1,2,3), all years between 2011 and 2022, and numerous countries.  Rows can be duplicated, and there are thousands of rows.

I want to add a new column, with a value of TRUE or FALSE.  I have a separate table (called Table1) telling me the number of TRUE values there should be for each year:

```
2018  2019  2020  2021  2022
 123   100    99   189   211
```

However, only rows with certain conditions can get a TRUE value - they have to be from 2018 onwards, they have to have Eng as their country, and if the year is 2018 then they have 2 as their Level (other years the Level doesn't matter).

I would like the original table to have this additional column for all rows, where the number of TRUES in each year match those in Table1.

I've tried various things.  I started trying to combine conditions with "&" together with a sample() function.

```
newtable <- df$Country == "Eng" &
            df$Level = 2 & 
            df$Year >= 2018 &
            sample(c(T,F),nrows(df),replace=T,prob=c(???))
```

but then got stuck on how the probabilities could differ between years, as well as how to convert the raw numbers in Table1 into probabilities.

I'm also stuck on how to apply a slightly different filter to 2018 (Level 2 only) - I can use this dplyr:filter `

```
filter(!(Year==2018 and Level!=2))
```

But I'm not sure how to incorporate this into my above function.
`

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: are you assigning `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on the data in your df, or are you assigning T/F values based on data in the original tables AND the number of `TRUE` values in table 1?

Comment: A couple of hints. First, create an `eligible` column, based on your eligibility conditions ("only rows with certain conditions can get a TRUE value"). Then, allocate the `T` among eligible rows for each year. E.g. suppose 2018 has 200 eligible rows. Then you would do `sample(c(rep(T, 123), rep(F, 77)), 200, replace = F)`, noting in particular that `replace = FALSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To indicate which rows are eligible to be assigned `TRUE`, you can use the following expression

```
df$eligible <- (df$Year > 2018 & df$Country == "Eng") | 
    (df$Year == 2018 & df$Country == "Eng" & df$Level == 2)
```

which says a row is eligible if `Year` is strictly greater than 2018 (i.e. 2019 or greater) *and* `Country` is "Eng", **OR** `Year` is 2018 *and* `Country` is "Eng" *and* `Level` is 2.

Now, allocate `TRUE`s among eligible rows. There are several ways to do this. One way is to split eligible rows by `Year` and allocate the `TRUE`s according to the values in the table.

```
eligible <- df[df$eligible, ]
trues <- c(123, 100, 99, 189, 211)
```

Now, using `mapply`:

```
new_df <- mapply(FUN = function(x, n) {
  x$new_column <- FALSE
  x$new_column[sample(1:nrow(x), n)] <- TRUE
  x
}, x = split(eligible, eligible$Year), n = trues, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

we create a function that takes two arguments: a dataframe of eligible rows, and the number of `TRUE`s for that dataframe, and returns the dataframe with a new column with randomly allocated `TRUE`s. `mapply` then applies the values of `split(eligible, eligible$Year)` (a list with five dataframes, each corresponding to a year between 2018 and 2022) and `trues` (a vector with five elements) in parallel to the function.

Finishing off,

```
new_df <- do.call(rbind, new_df)
new_df <- rbind(new_df, cbind(df[!df$eligible, ], new_column = FALSE))
```

we row-bind the output of `mapply(...)` (a list with five dataframes) together, and then `rbind` that to the non-eligible rows with the new column appended where the values are, by definition, `FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you very much - that worked perfectly.  I hadn't thought of using a "helper" eligible column, and your explanation was really clear, and helped me understand mapply function as well, which I hadn't used before.